# Angularjs template view is not being cached, it refreshes every time

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, caching, model-view-controller

Scratching my head on this one, I have a tab that has two views in it, the default view and a secondary view.  The user must click a button (in the default view) to get to the secondary view...and once in the secondary view must click a button to go back to the default view.

I have `cache: true,` on both views and caching is working (as intended) on the default view, but is not working on the secondary view.  Every time the user goes to the secondary view it refreshes the content with a call to the server.  Regardless of which view the user is on, if the user goes to another tab and comes back again, neither default or secondary views get refreshed (as intended), its only when switching from the default view to the secondary view does it happen.

There is nothing else in the controllers for either views that is messing with or dealing with cache.  How can I resolve this or what can I look for that might be causing this?

In app.js:

```
  .state('tab.current', {  // primary/default view
    cache: true,
    url: '/current',
    params: tabParams,
    views: {
      'tab-current': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-current.html',
        controller: 'CurrentCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.current-detail', {
    cache: true,
    url: '/current/:ceID',
    params: tabParams,
    views: {
      'tab-current': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/detail-current.html',
        controller: 'CurrentDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  
  .state('tab.past', {  // secondary view
    cache: true,
    url: '/past',
    params: tabParams,
    views: {
      'tab-current': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-past.html',
        controller: 'PastCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.past-detail', {
    cache: true,
    url: '/past/:ceID',
    params: tabParams,
    views: {
      'tab-current': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/detail-past.html',
        controller: 'PastDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

I am using Ionic tabs:

```
<ion-tabs id="allTabs" delegate-handle="mainTabs" class="tabs-icon-bottom tabs-bottom tabs-color-active-positive" style="">
  <div id="allTabsBar" style="height:100%;">
    <!-- Home Tab   -->
    <ion-tab id="homeTab" class="icon barIconHeight" icon-off="ion-home" icon-on="ion-home" href="#/tab/home" >
      <ion-nav-view id="tab-home" name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Club Tab   -->
    <ion-tab id="clubTab" class="icon barIconHeight" icon-off="ion-people" icon-on="ion-people" href="#/tab/clubs" >
      <ion-nav-view id="tab-clubs" name="tab-clubs"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Search Tab   -->
    <ion-tab id="searchTab" class="icon barIconHeight" icon-off="ion-search" icon-on="ion-search" href="#/tab/search" >
      <ion-nav-view id="tab-search" name="tab-search"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <!-- Settings Tab   -->
    <ion-tab id="menuTab" class="icon barIconHeight" icon-off="ion-ios-settings-strong" icon-on="ion-ios-settings-strong" href="#/tab/menu" >
      <ion-nav-view id="tab-menu" name="tab-menu"></ion-nav-view> <!-- class="icon ion-ios-settings-strong" -->
    </ion-tab>

  </div>
</ion-tabs
```

Comment: Could you provide each controller or template snippet responsible for triggering each navigation in question? Also are you using ui-router? Is it only fetching the template html again or is a full page load being triggered?

Comment: @MarkClark - i updated OP.  Its doing a full page load every time that page view is put in focus. The primary/default page does not do this, only going to the subView.  The subview has its own controller, but is a part of the main tab view (ie: `views: 'tab-current'`)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is likely your usage of href. AngularJS probably isn't getting a chance to pass off your hash routing to the location service. Since the template cache is not backed by any persistence layer (local/session storage), a full page reload will clear any cached templates.

See [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)